# Duda con mostrar camas no usadas por pacientes en Genexus

Tags: genexus

¿Como puedo hacer para que en el Grid que dice "Cama libres" me muestre todas las camas que no estan siendo usadas por los pacientes ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolvería con un evento load del grid que haga la carga usando una condición NOT IN de las camas libres que las devuelve un Data Selector.

Abajo un ejemplo

```
Event GridCamasLibres.Load
    for each Cama
        where NOT NumeroCama in DSCamasOcupadas()
        
        &NumeroCamaLibre = NumeroCama
        &HabitacionCamaLibre = NumeroHabitacion
        Load
    endfor
EndEvent
```

El Data Selector, asumiendo que la cama está ocupada si no tiene fecha de egreso, sería:

```
DSCamasOcupadas
Parameters: none
Conditions: FechaEgresoPaciente = Nullvalue(&FechaEgresoPaciente)
DefinedBy:FechaIngresoPaciente
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias. Estaba pensando que capas seria mejor si en vez de mostrar las camas libres por separado las pueda mostrar en el primer grid (en donde se muestran todos los datos de las internaciones). Por ejemplo que al abrir la ventana internaciones se carguen automáticamente las camas libres en el grid y que el resto de datos como "CI Paciente" o "N Internación" se muestren con un guion o que queden en blanco, así después le doy al boton de "Update" y cargo los datos que faltan. ¿ Alguna sugerencia de como puedo hacer eso o si es posible?

Comment: Si lo que querés es tener una lista de las camas disponibles para asignar en esa internación, lo que haría es que el campo NumeroCama se muestre en ese primer grid con un Dynamic Combo Box que tenga Data Source un Data Provider y crear un  Data Provider con las mismas condiciones que el for each anterior. https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?22948,HowTo%3A+Use+the+Data+Source+From+property